# MySql from Windows to ubunto

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, xampp, lamp

i have all table of mysql with examp as files now i install ubuntu i want to get databases in ubuntu sql just i had copy mysql from data to var/lib/mysql
but when i brows tables give me this error

```
/libraries/tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php#243
Undefined index: Default
```

Backtrace

```
./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#513: include(./libraries/tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php)
./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#179: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->displayHtmlForColumnChange(
array,
string 'tbl_structure.php',
)
./tbl_structure.php#49: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->indexAction()
```

Comment: On your `windows` environment, you dump your databases into a sql file(mysqldump)....and in your `Linux` environment just restore using that file...check this article http://mysqlserverteam.com/creating-and-restoring-database-backups-with-mysqldump-and-mysql-enterprise-backup-part-1-of-2/

Comment: thank you but now i don't have OS Windows in my computer i just have files.